# flask mysql connect error on Mac OSX 10.12.6

Tags: python, mysql, macos, flask

/Users/apple/myapp2/env/bin/python3 /Users/apple/myapp2/testmysql2/app.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/myapp2/testmysql2/app.py", line 2, in 
    **flask_mysqldb import MySQL**
  File "/Users/apple/myapp2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/**init**.py", line 1, in 
    **import MySQLdb**
  File "/Users/apple/myapp2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 18, in 
    **from . import _mysql**
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/apple/myapp2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
  Referenced from: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Process finished with exit code 1

**Other info:**

(env) (base) MacBook-Air:testmysql2 apple$ otool -L /Users/apple/myapp2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so

**/Users/apple/myapp2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so:**
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib (compatibility version 21.0.0, current version 21.0.0)
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'testuser'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'testpw'
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'formdb'

    mysql = MYSQL(app)
```

I want to connect mysql to flask app, but got such error, I don't know how to fix it.

What's that mean

**Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

 in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib**

?

And my mac is Mac OS X 10.12

Also I will look for another way to connect mysql to flask, it too hard for me to solve the problem :)

It's my first time to ask question, maybe there are some format problems, not clear to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the pymysql. And the include pymysql in your database string uri like below:

```
'pymysql://root:root@localhost/your_database?charset=utf8mb4'
```

It will work I have also faced the same issue this resolved my issue

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried to use pymysql, and I connected flask successfully.